# "Comment Selection" command is not currently available in Visual Studio C++ editor MEF extension

Tags: visual-studio, comments, editor, visual-studio-extensions, extensibility

We want to extend the Visual Studio C++ editor using an MEF component to add some features to it. To do so, We used the C/C++ BaseDefinition:

```
[Export]
[Name("mycpp")]
[BaseDefinition("C/C++")]
```

Everything works fine except for the comment/uncomment selection commands which are greyed out in the toolbar. Also, when using CTRL+K, CTRL+C, we get the following message:

*The key combination (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C) is bound to command (Comment Selection) which is not currently available.*

Anybody knows why this is not working and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Does (CTRL+K, CTRL+C) works fine before you extend the Visual Studio C++ editor?

Comment: Yes. Without the extension, everything works fine.